# Express.js Cannot find module 'mime-types'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to run a simple express server with body-parser:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

I realize this is no longer bundled with express and have double checked both packages are installed with:

```
npm install -s express body-parser
```

The error I get back is:

```
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mime-types'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/osboxes/.nvm/versions/node/v7.2.0/lib/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/type-is/index.js:16:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

I've also tried:

```
 npm install -s mime-types
```

which had no effect.

*Note: I verified that line 4 is where the error occurs by logging before and after.*

Comment: As far as I know you have to use `npm i -S` (with capital `S`) to save dependencies in `package.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure `body-parser` and `express` are listed as dependencies in your `package.json`, then delete your whole `node_modules` directory and do a clean install of your dependencies using `npm i`.

It looks like `mime-types` is a dependency of the `type-is` which `body-parser` has listed as a dependency, make sure that all of those are installed properly and if not install them. You shouldn't need to a `--save` flag when installing `mime-types` because you don't need to make it a dependency of your package since you're already listing `body-parser` as a dependency, if anything that could cause another problem because you may have a differing version requirement from that of `body-parser`/`type-is`.

Also, I don't believe the save flag for npm is `-s` it is either `--save` or `-S`.

> npm install takes 3 exclusive, optional flags which save or update the package version in your main package.json:
>
> -S, --save: Package will appear in your dependencies.
>
> -D, --save-dev: Package will appear in your devDependencies.
>
> -O, --save-optional: Package will appear in your optionalDependencies.